# Generate new column based on column of dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So I have a DataFrame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [dict(F='y', G='v'),'F'],
        [dict(F='y', G='v'),'G'],
    ], columns=list('AB'))
```

I need to generate a new column C, based on column B and get sth like this

```
pd.DataFrame([
        [dict(F='y', G='v'),'F','y'],
        [dict(F='y', G='v'),'G','v'],
    ], columns=list('ABC'))
```

I am thinking of using apply function, but failed

Comment: What do you want column C to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get` method for possible get default value if no match:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'].get(x['B']), axis=1)

#if values always match
#df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'][x['B']], axis=1)
print (df)
                      A  B  C
0  {'F': 'y', 'G': 'v'}  F  y
1  {'F': 'y', 'G': 'v'}  G  v
```